# I have a mysql query in my php code that is cut and pasted in two places. How can I get it to be in one place?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in index.php and the exact same query in update.php. How can I have the query in a single location so it's easy to manage?

This is my query:

```
$sets=$_GET["sets"];
$sets = "'" . str_replace(array("'", ","), array("\\'", "','"), $sets) . "'";

// test code
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `cards`
    WHERE
        `setName` in ($sets)
    ORDER BY
        `setName` DESC,
    LIMIT
        500
";
```

Comment: What kind of a query is it, what does it do? If you want a good answer architecture-wise (instead of just the info how to define a constant or something), add more information.

Comment: Write a [function](http://www.php.net/functions.user-defined) and place it in an include/lib script.

Comment: put it in another file and include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a `header.php`, or a `functions.php`. Then, define the queries within the file. You can then access them, after including them.

```
require 'header.php';
    OR
include 'header.php';



function make_query($val)
{
    $res = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . $val;
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, is there a way to pass values to the query?

Comment: language construct's don't need the brackets

Comment: @rotaercz any variable defined on the page before with induce can be used in the code from the include. include is just an internal cut and paste

Comment: See my edit for an example of using a function to pass an unknwon parameter into a future query (don't take the example too literally). also thanks @Dagon

Comment: Yes, hi, thank you for the sure justice, "don't take the example too literally"

Answer (score 0):

Create a third file `query.php`, put the query in this file (maybe in a variable) and include the file from both `index.php` and `update.php`.